# How can I save the output of DIG in CSV format?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am using DIG command in linux and getting results i want but how can i get output results written in CSV file and get them saved ?

Current output is below which i want in csv file :

```
inspectieSZW.nl.        19      IN      A       178.22.85.166
inspectieSZW.nl.        19      IN      A       178.22.85.169
belgique.be.            6940    IN      A       193.191.245.244
belgie.be.              6940    IN      A       193.191.245.244
christiemorreale.be.    3340    IN      A       128.65.195.89
regards.fr.             340     IN      A       137.74.167.22
dragons.jp.             19      IN      A       52.198.194.108
dragons.jp.             19      IN      A       18.182.191.127
j-sm.jp.                79      IN      A       49.212.243.98
ndenter.co.kr.          3341    IN      A       223.26.138.51
semillasdelfuturo.com.co. 341   IN      A       50.62.88.87
redesdamare.org.br.     3342    IN      A       149.56.157.48
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter every `dig` command like this (replace [HOSTNAME] by the host name you want to DIG):

```
dig [HOSTNAME] | grep IN | grep -v ";" | tr -s "[:blank:]" "," >> savedoutput.csv
```

1. The first `grep` leaves only the lines containing "IN".
2. The second `grep` removes the line starting with `;` in the QUESTION SECTION.
3. The `tr` command replaces all spaces by commas.
4. The `>>` appends all output to the file called `savedoutput.csv`.

Comment: Thanks , that worked like a charm . I am using big list of domains and there are several domains where are no NS results for domains and DIG is skipping domains with no results hence not writing or mentioning them in output file , is there anyway i can get those domains with no NS results also written in output file ?

Comment: please help , i am noob in linux and just followed a tutorial and stuck here

Comment: That is a different question, and also more complicated than the normal case. Please post a new question with this problem; the friendly people here will probably help you with a script that takes the hostname as a parameter and outputs a line if no NS results are found.

Answer (score 1):

Converting output from dig to csv format using sed.

```
$ sed <(dig askubuntu.com) > out.csv \
  -nE -e '/^[^;].*IN/{s/[[:blank:]]+/,/g;p}'
```